# Writing Contract-First Web Service using Spring Integration

Tags: java, web-services, soap, spring-integration, spring-ws

I need to create a `SOAP` based `Web Service` using `Spring Integration` which will process the request payload in a `Service Activator` and then generate and send the appropriate response.

`WSDL` file is in my hand along with `XSDs` for request and response message. So I need to create the web service using `WSDL`.

If anyone can provide any example or tutorial on this subject??

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [Spring Integration Sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/ws-inbound-gateway) on the matter gives you answers.
And some info in the [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/ws.html#webservices-inbound)

1. You need to configure Spring WS infrastructure (see its documentations).
2. Refer your `<int-ws:inbound-gateway>` to the `org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.UriEndpointMapping` as `defaultEndpoint`.
3. And go ahead with other your business logic.

Comment: Thanks Artem, I have started working on the example you referred. However I am using JDK1.5 compilation and getting below error:
bad class file: (org/springframework/integration/xml/source/DomSourceFactory.class)
class file has wrong version 50.0, should be 49.0

Comment: can you suggest which version should i use for spring and spring integration compliance 1.5

Comment: Sorry for late reply: haven't been notified. The Java 1.5 EOF for a long time already. And 1.6, too. So, it's bad to use so old java version for Spring now.